# Solving $\cos^6(2x)+\sin^6(2x)=\frac58$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve the following equation for $x$?

$$\cos^6(2x)+\sin^6(2x)=\frac58$$

Thanks

Comment: You will find that it helps to let us know about your attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$$

$$\implies\cos^62x+\sin^62x=(\cos^22x)^3+(\sin^22x)^3=1-3\cos^22x\sin^22x$$

$$=1-\frac34(2\cos2x\sin2x)^2$$

$$=1-\frac34(\sin^24x)$$

$$=1-\frac34\cdot\frac{1-\cos8x}2$$

Finally $\cos y=\cos A\implies y=2m\pi\pm A$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 3):

Using $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y=2\cos^2y-1,$

$$5=(2\sin^22x)^3+(2\cos^22x)^3=(1-\cos4x)^3+(1+\cos4x)^3=2+2(3\cos^24x)$$

$$2\cos^24x=1\iff\cos8x=0$$

$$\implies8x=(2m+1)\frac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^4-a^2b^2+b^4),$$then use $\sin^2 y= 1-\cos^2y$.